# Is Windows 10 [Password protection on wakeup] set to 'Required' relevant when machine is asleep?

Tags: passwords, network, windows-10

I like to just hit the spacebar and have the machine ready without the extra fuss (many times a day.)

***No one untrusted has physical access to the machine***, but it wakes up at ~3am and does updates and maintenance and such (I assume Windows *and* various apps initiate this.)  The machine is connected to the Internet 24/7.

So my question is: Does requiring Ctrl-Alt-Del + Password 'significantly' help protect it from attackers over the Internet when it's sleeping?  Because, I imagine that attacks of that nature, hard as they may be at this point, by definition of complexity have access at a level such that this setting is irrelevant.

I have a router/firewall, boot UEFI, always use an account *without* Administrative rights day-to-day, use Malwarebytes Pro on top of Windows Defender, and everything I can is set to “auto-update” – if any of that alters the specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't protect you from attacks over the internet (that's also not its intended purpose), unless you are using a VNC type of remote desktop solution. Ctrl-alt-del is more a protection from opportunists passing by your computer (physically).

Remote connectivity options like RDP always require valid credentials before a connection is established, even if the computer is unlocked on your side.